# Код для задачи зацикливается, не могу понять почему

Tags: python, циклы

Всем доброго времени суток!
Краткое условие задачи: на вход подается натуральное число, нужно посчитать его "разностный корень". То есть, если число находится в промежутке [0;9], то корень равен самому числу. Если это число 2693, например, то корень считается как модуль разности соседних цифр. |2-6||6-9||9-3|= 436, поскольку число 436 еще не однозначное, нужно проделать это еще раз. |4-3||3-6|=13 и еще раз |1-3|=2. 2 это окончательный ответ.
Написал код, но он зацикливается

```
n = input()
s=''
if int(n)>=0 and int(n)<=9:
    print(n)
else:
    while int(n)>9:
        for i in range(len(n)-1):
            s+= str(abs(int(n[i])-int(n[i+1])))
        n = n.replace(n,s)
    print(n)
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Просто совет на будущее: в подобных ситуация используй отладку или пихай принты. Попробовал бы повыводить содержимое n и s - и увидел бы безмерно разрастающийся s заполняющий весь вывод как вирус из матрицы xD.

Answer (score 2):

`s` надо очищать перед каждым подходом, т.е. в начале цикла `while`.
В конце цикла вместо невнятного `replace` сделать простое присвоение.
Ну и `if` с обвязкой там вообще лишний.

Да и вообще:

```
n = input()
while int(n)>9:
    n = n.lstrip("0")
    n = "".join(str(abs(int(a)-int(b))) for a,b in zip(n, n[1:]))
print(n)
```

Comment: да, так гораздо компактнее, я писал, что первое пришло в голову.
но этот код не работает правильно на числах 1135 и 18113, выводит у обоих 2, вместо 0 и 5 соответственно

Comment: поправил код строчкой `n=n.lstrip("0")`, теперь все работает

Comment: Двойное преобразование int. Разумнее `n=[int(d) for d in n.lstrip('0')]`, а потом просто `abs(a-b)`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = input()
if int(n)>=0 and int(n)<=9:
    print(n)
else:
    while int(n)>9:
        s = ''
        for i in range(len(n)-1):
            s+= str(abs(int(n[i])-int(n[i+1])))
        n = s
    print(n.strip('0'))
```

Надо обнулять `s`

Comment: Да и `if` тут в принципе не нужен.

Comment: Спасибо! Основную ошибку с s понял. Но не работает для числа 1135, выводит 2, вместо 0

Comment: @GrAnd, но с отрицательными числами в любом случае будет фигня.

Answer (score 0):

По мотивам решения @GrAnd, без постоянного преобразования строка-число-строка

```
n = input()
n = [int(d) for d in n]
while len(n) > 1:
    if n[0] == 0: n = n[1:]
    n = [abs(a-b) for a,b in zip(n, n[1:])]
print(n[0])
```